# Can we use dynamic feature modules as SDK?

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, dynamic-delivery

I am currently developing an application which uses multiple [dynamic feature modules](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/dynamic-delivery). I was wondering if I can ship the same .aab modules as an independent SDK. If not what is the cost of converting the .aab feature to .aar file. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you learn anything about this? I am also interested.